# How to handle multiple actions in a single form in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, dmi

I have a form contains three buttons `print`/`export`/`save`.

```
<s:form action="/userAction">
    <s:submit type="image" value="%{'print'}" src="/print.png" />
    <s:submit type="image" value="%{'export'}" src="/export.png" />
    <s:submit type="image" value="%{'save'}" src="/save.png" />
</s:form>
```

How can I map this in `struts.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `struts.xml` the action is mapped via the [`action` tag](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#action-mappings)

```xml
<action name="userAction" class="...
```

the `submit` buttons should include `method` attribute to call corresponding methods of the action

```jsp
<s:submit type="image" value="%{'print'}" src="/print.png" method="print" />
<s:submit type="image" value="%{'export'}" src="/export.png" method="export" />
<s:submit type="image" value="%{'save'}" src="/save.png" method="save" />
```

**Note**: To map a `method` attribute you should have [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) turned on.

Comment: You can also use action annotations over xml if you prefer. An action class can have it's methods exposed with dynamic method invocation in a couple ways: https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-DynamicMethodInvocation I just like to make distinct actions and just use namespace and action attributes of the s:submit button.

Comment: @Roman C: so I have to write three <action> tags with same name="userAction" and different methods. In that case all the methods return success. how will struts know the response is from save() or export()?

Comment: When you map an action, there is a result. If you use DMI (dynamic method invocation) then the mapping for the action applies (that result will be used) but you use a different method other than execute. If you want a different result per method then the method should be mapped as an action. A single action class can support multiple actions, you just need to define them with xml or annotations.

Comment: @javabie If you configure `<action` tag you can place only one attribute `method` and only one mapping to that method. The `<action` configuration allows to have many results. If you want to return different result you should configure them there. You can give different names for results to say "save" or "export". But it's only useful if you return different results to the same action that has results with different types and values.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `method` attribute of the `<s:submit>` tag `DynamicMethodInvocation` must be enabled. Another solution is to use `action` attribute.

In JSP:

```
<s:form action="save">
    <s:submit type="image" value="%{'print'}" src="/print.png" action="print" />
    <s:submit type="image" value="%{'export'}" src="/export.png" action="export" />
    <s:submit type="image" value="%{'save'}" src="/save.png" />
</s:form>
```

In struts.xml:

```
<action name="print" class="...">
  <result>...</result>
</action>
<action name="export" class="...">
  <result>...</result>
</action>
<action name="save" class="...">
  <result>...</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Struts doc : https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation