# WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: in namespace: Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, dmi

I am trying to find the namespace and action name with wildcards but it gets failed.

**Exception :**

```
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: '/checkMethods/executeCRUD' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
```

**XML :**

```xml
<package name="crudAction" namespace="/checkMethods" extends="struts-default" >
    <action name="*CRUD" class="leo.struts.HelloWorldAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="success" >/crud.jsp</result>
    </action>       
</package>
```

**JSP:**

```jsp
<body>
    Action so Far : <s:property value="message"/>
        <s:form action="/checkMethods/deleteCRUD" >            
            <s:submit label="delete"/>
        </s:form>
        <s:form action="/checkMethods/selectCRUD" >            
            <s:submit label="select"/>
        </s:form>
        <s:form action="/checkMethods/updateCRUD" >            
            <s:submit label="update"/>
        </s:form>
        <s:form action="/checkMethods/executeCRUD" >            
            <s:submit label="execute"/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `action` attribute you should specify the action name without slashes. Like

```
<s:form namespace="/checkMethods" action="deleteCRUD" >
```

That would resolve [action mappings](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#action-mappings) but it will not save you from updating data.

Having multiple `form`s on the page separate the `input` fields by the [`s:form` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/form-tag.html).

If you want to have several buttons mapped to each own action that operate on the same data then you should create one form and several submit tags, and each tag map to the `method` or `action` attribute.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467399/573032) answer how to do it.

> the `submit` buttons should include `method` attribute to call corresponding methods of the action

Comment: Thanks for reply,pls help me to understand.then how to call using normal form <form action="deleteCRUD" here no namespace attribute></form> here how to call the namespace ?.

Comment: In the HTML form you have to build URL manually, if you don't know the syntax you should check the source code generated in the browser. url tag could be useful.

Comment: YES thanks , first i removed `.action` extension from `action="deleteCRUD.action"` and  i added the namespace i think the attribute namespace required is that correct ?

Comment: @shareef What do you think about namespace? It's correct, but not related to the question as to be a thin thing regarding the action mapping well answered in some other of my answers.