# How do I handle multiple actions in single form in wildcard action mapping?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, wildcard-mapping, dmi

According this solution [Struts2 handle multiple actions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466733/struts2-handle-multiple-actions-in-single-form) I know the Struts2 DMI can handle multiple acitons in single form easily.

Recently, Struts2 turned off DMI mechanism for security issue. Now, we use Wildcard Mappings to map all actions in `struts.xml`

**Example:**

```
<action name="*/*" class="action.{1}Action" method="{2}">
    ...
</action>
```

In Wildcard Mappings, it has a little problem to deal with mapping multiple actions/methods in single form.

```
<s:form action="actionA/method2" theme="simple" >
    <s:submit value="lastStep"  action="actionA/method1"/>
    <s:submit value="nextStep" />
</s:form>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13343954/1700321?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Struts2 even if [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) is turned off still possible to use special parameter `action:`. To use this parameter in JSP you need to configure

in your `struts.xml` file:

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
```

Special parameters are handled by the action mapper when filter is trying to get action mapping from the filtered URL, and this parameter is added to the form when you use `action` attribute of the `submit` tag.

Comment: Why do you think you need to remove it from excluded parameters? It is *special* parameter you don't want it to be manipulated.