# How to invoke multiple methods from Struts 2.5 with SMI and when DMI is off

Tags: struts2, dmi

Right now we are using Struts 2.5 and I have    `Dynamic Method Invocation=true` in Struts configuration file .

And i have action mappings as below.

```xml
<action name="action name" class="action class"
   <result name="view" type="redirectAction"></result>
   <allowed-methods> 
         view,modify,delete,duplicate 
   </allowed-methods>
</action>
```

To remediate App-sec finding i have to set Dynamic Method Invocation to `false`.

I have set `Dynamic Method Invocation value="false"` . Now allowed methods are not working.

I did specify multiple actions with methods, it did not work as well. It is calling default `reset` and `process` method from the `Action` class instead the specified method.

I have read that for `allowed-methods` to work we have to have Dynamic Method Invocation set to `true`?

How do i call multiple methods with the same action with disabling Dynamic Method Invocation?

Comment: In struts2 each action is mapped to the method of the action class. No need to break this rule. See how to use a special parameter in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494411/573032) answer.

Answer (score 1):

If DMI is turned off you cannot invoke methods dynamically; that's the point of turning it off.

You can use [Strict Method Invocation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration#strict-method-invocation) to explicitly allow methods; SMI is enabled by default.

You can't have it both ways--DMI is either enabled, or not.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your input. But allowed methods is not working when I turned off DMI.  Could you please let me know the necessary changes that I should make in my Struts configuration file in order to have the allowed methods working with SMI.

Comment: @Sailaja ... Turn on DMI. If DMI is turned off you cannot invoke methods dynamically, that's the point.