# Multiple Submit Button Mapping in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a Struts 2 Form whose form action is mapped to the `processForm` Action, with multiple Submit buttons pointing to specific methods in that Form Action using `method=`.

```
<s:form id='myForm' action="processForm">
   <!-- ... -->
   <s:submit id="method1" method="method1" name="method1" value="1"/>
   <s:submit id="method2" method="method2" name="method2" value="2"/>
   <s:submit id="method3" method="method3" name="method3" value="3"/>
</s:form>
```

Suppose the Action class that handles it is `MyFormAction`:

```
public class MyFormAction extends BaseAction {
        public String method1() {
           // ...
        }  
        public String method2() {
           // ...
        }
        public String method3() {
           // ...
        }
}
```

I found that in **struts.xml**, if I just specify the first method, all button clicks resolve successfully, without me adding specific blocks for the other methods:

```
<action name="processForm" class="myapp.action.MyFormAction" method="method1">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
         <param name="actionName">homeaction</param>
    </result>
</action>
<!-- No other mappings defined for method2/method3, but they work -->
```

If there is no action mapping at all for `processForm` then everything fails.

So my question is, what is the proper way to define multi-Submit mappings inside a single Form Action in **struts.xml**? Do I just go ahead and manually define every single method explicitly, even though it works "implicitly"? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746418/573032

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm not asking how to handle a single Submit button (either with a Form `action=` or a single Submit's `method=`). I'm asking how to map **multiple** Submit buttons pointing to different methods in a Form.

Comment: If you know how to invoke a method on a submit button then you should think to have multiple submit buttons that are bound to the methods of the action class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467399/573032